# Why would EF not update an object when called from Console application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, console-application, entity-framework-5

My solution consists of several projects including an MVC 3 website and a console application.

I am following the repository pattern with EF.

Everything works fine from the MVC app but when I try to update an object via the console application, nothing happens.

I am able to retrieve the object from the console app and change its properties but when I go to save the changes, the row is not updated. No errors or anything. Am I missing something here?

I have the same connection string to the DB configured in the MVC app and Console app config files.

Comment: Have you actually stepped into the entity framework data context to make sure it is being hit correctly?  Something might rise to the surface there.

Comment: Could you please post some code from the console app?

Comment: Fixed it. Had to deal with db context not being reused properly

Comment: Why don't you put that as the answer, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was related to the DB Context not being reused correctly in the Console app. Basically a new context was being created for both the read and write. I needed to configure my DI(Ninject) to create my context in the correct scope.